# Response returning html code instead of XML

Tags: c#

I am sending XML data using HTTP POST to a specified URL.Expected response is to be in XML format. But I am receiving HTML code instead of XML.I am sending my sample post code.

```
string postData = null;
postData = "NETCONNECT_TRANSACTION=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(xdoc.ToString());

HttpWebRequest experianRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("some url");
experianRequest.Method = "POST";
experianRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
string UserIDFormated = "username:password";
experianRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization: BASIC" + ConvertToBase64String(UserIDFormated));
experianRequest.Timeout = 100000;
experianRequest.KeepAlive = false;
experianRequest.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] byteData;
byteData = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
experianRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
experianRequest.ContentLength = byteData.Length;
Stream newStream = experianRequest.GetRequestStream();
newStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
newStream.Close();

HttpWebResponse experianResponse = (HttpWebResponse)experianRequest.GetResponse();

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(experianResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
//XmlTextReader objxml = new XmlTextReader(newStream2);
//XmlDocument xdocresponse = new XmlDocument();
//xdocresponse.Load(experianResponse.GetResponseStream());
//string root = xdocresponse.DocumentElement.OuterXml;
//XDocument xdocresponse = XDocument.Load(objxml);
//objxml.Close();
//experianResponse.Close();
//StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(newStream2);
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();
//newStream.Close();
experianResponse.Close();
```

Comment: I suggest you read the HTML response to see what it is trying to tell you.

Comment: Recieving following html code

Comment: <html><head>........function setfocus(){var app = findApp();
  initApp(app.id);
  window.location = app.logonUrl;}<body onload="setfocus()"></body>

Comment: I suggested that _you_ read it, not that _I_ read it!

Comment: I meant read it with your eyes. What does it say? If that's the entire response, then the service thinks it's sending to a web browser, and you're out of luck with your current approach. Maybe you're calling it the wrong way?